# Python function default argument random value

Tags: python, function, random

In the following code, a random value is generated as expected:

```
import random

for i in range(10):
    print(random.randint(0,10))
```

However, this does not work if I use a function:

```
import random

def f(val: int = random.randint(0,10)):
    print(val)

for i in range(10):
    f()
```

Why is the result of the second code snippet always the same number? The most similar question I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number) one, but it refers to a different language (I don't master) .

Comment: It's because arguments are evaluated only once. You can search "python default arguments" for more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it did lead me to this article: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm , which answers my question. But by the time I return to the thread, there are answers already. Thank you for linking your suggested read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default argument expression isn't evaluated when you *call* the function, it's evaluated when you *create* the function.  So you'll always get the same value no matter what you do.

The typical way around this is to use a flag value and replace it inside the body of the function:

```
def f(val=None):
    if val is None:
        val = random.randint(0,10)
    print(val)
```

Comment: Chose this as the answer because it states when/how **val** is evaluated. I understand it is like a _static_ local variable in C

Comment: @mushishi I always try to emphasize that point, because I'm familiar with C++ which does it the other way around - default arguments are evaluated at call time.  Calling it a *static* isn't quite accurate, rather the function `f` becomes an object and the argument list and defaults become attributes of that object.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to have the default value be a specific value. To make it be dynamic like that, you'll want to default it to something else, check for that, and then change the value.

For example:

```py
import random

def f(val=None):
    if val is None:
        val = random.randint(0,10)
    print(val)

for i in range(10):
    f()
```

Answer (score 0):

The default param can't be changed on calling.
I can't understand why it needed.
you can do  simply like this.

```
import random
def f():
  print(random.randint(0,10))
for i in range(10):
  f()
```

Comment: This is an oversimplification from real-world code. I could check whether the default argument is set and if no, return; but I was curious why I cannot save myself the extra couple of lines